# Linq to EF not returning all data

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have following query against EF whereby mysql was used:

```
var query = from r in context.myContext
            where r.clmn1.CompareTo("2015-11-19 00:00:00") > 0)
            orderby r.someColumn
            select r;
return query;
```

The number of returned rows is as expected. however some values of the property `r.clmn2` repeat itself in the result of the query. For example I could not find `clmn2 == 220011` because it was "overwritten" by the value 220033 (The value `220033` is correct and expected but should not "overwrite" other values). Strangely enough, when I add this condition to the query I get it in the result (of course then only and only this value) which means that the first condition is also valid for `clmn2`:

```
var query = from r in context.myContext
            where r.clmn1.CompareTo("2015-11-19 00:00:00") > 0) && r.clmn2.Equals("220011")
            orderby r.someColumn
            select r;
return query;
```

The same query (the first one) works at DB-level and returns all values (will not be overwritten)

```
SELECT * FROM myContext.myTable
WHERE r.clmn1 > ("2015-11-19 00:00:00")
ORDER BY r.someColumn
```

It should be a problem of EF. I hope someone could help me!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how does your dbconetxt and your db look like?

Comment: Also, it gets overwritten in all the previous querys exept the last one ? caus the only diference i see is the comparTo() function

Comment: Hallo, I could find the solution. Tha problem was in the entity class where the columns are definde as properties. I have prefixed this property with [key] atribute so it is now a part of the multiple key, i.e., with other properties. It works!. Tanks for ur interesst.

Answer (score 0):

I have prefixed the column/property clmn2 with [key] atribute in the generated entity class so that it is now a part of the multiple key, i.e., with other columns/properties. It works and i get all values from DB. Maybe cus this property comes from a DB-view, Visual Studio could not recognize it as a primary key as done by other properties.